# Error while dividing two metrices in prometheus

Tags: mongodb, prometheus

I am trying to divide below two metrices .

```
rate(mongodb_mongod_metrics_query_executor_total{instance=~"$env",port="$port",state=~"scanned_objects"}[$interval])
 /rate(mongodb_mongod_metrics_document_total{instance=~"$env",port="$port",state=~"returned"}[$interval])
```

but it's giving error

> method:"GET" hideFromInspector:false response:Object error:"" response:"1:5: parse error: unexpected character: '\ufeff'" message:"1:5: parse error: unexpected character: '\ufeff'"

What's wrong I am doing??

Comment: You forgot to mention what's the error that you get.

Comment: error:
method:"GET"
hideFromInspector:false
response:Object
error:""
response:"1:5: parse error: unexpected character: '\ufeff'"
message:"1:5: parse error: unexpected character: '\ufeff'"

Comment: Apparently some of your variables contain an invalid value.